# Exchange 2016 - IMAP/SMTP Auth on port 587

Tags: authentication, smtp, exchange-server

need help with Outlook, to use smtp port 587 for outgoing mail.
The problem is, I cannot authenticate user on port 587 (Client Frontend Connector), but if I change SMTP port to 465 (Client Proxy connector), then AUTH is working.
The port 25, for anonymous is working, but I want to AUTH users. Why is port 465 working and 587 is rejecting AUTH?

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you haven't upgraded to a TLS connection using the `STARTTLS` SMTP command before trying to use the `AUTH` command.